# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Floor'

Tags: android, tensorflow

I use Tensorflow(Now master: 056db850614e0a06ce6f65b30f877c5789ab74f5). I generated graph file by `tf.train.write_graph`. It was loaded in JNI code.

I get the following error message on Run(`Status::error_message`):

```
No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Floor' with these attrs
[[Node: fc1/dropout/Floor = Floor[T=DT_FLOAT](fc1/dropout/add)]]
```

`fc1` is the name of fully-connected layer. The `Floor` had been used in `tf.nn.dropout`? I don't know it.

What should I do? Please tell me... Thanks.

---

JNI code. (It has been omitted part.)

```
ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), model_name, &graph);
summarizer.reset(new tensorflow::StatSummarizer(graph));
session->Create(graph);
graph.Clear();

tensorflow::Tensor x(
    tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,
    tensorflow::TensorShape({64}));
auto m = x.flat<float>();
// x was initialized here.
tensorflow::Tensor keep_prob(
    tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,
    tensorflow::TensorShape());
auto k = keep_prob.scalar<float>();
k() = 1.0;

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs({
        {"x",         x},
        {"keep_prob", keep_prob}});
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
std::vector<std::string> output_names({"ask"});
std::vector<std::string> targets({});

tensorflow::RunOptions options;
    options.set_trace_level(tensorflow::RunOptions::FULL_TRACE);
tensorflow::RunMetadata metadata;

status = session->Run(options, inputs, output_names, targets, &outputs, &metadata);

if(!status.ok()){
    // output status::error_message():
    //     No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Floor' with these attrs
    //     [[Node: fc1/dropout/Floor = Floor[T=DT_FLOAT](fc1/dropout/add)]]
}
```

Python code(omitted):

```
def inference(self, x, keep_prob):
    # build graph ...
    with tf.name_scope('fc1') as scope:
        Wf1 = weight_variable([256, 1024])
        bf1 = bias_variable([1024])
        hp2f = tf.reshape(hp2, [-1, 256])
        hf1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hp2f, Wf1) + bf1)
        hf_drop = tf.nn.dropout(hf1, keep_prob)  # Here is 'fc1/dropout/Floor'?
    # ...
    with tf.name_scope('softmax') as scope:
        y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(hf_drop, Wf2) + bf2, name='logits')
    return y

def op_ask(self, logits):
    return tf.identity(logits, name='ask:0')

def __init__(self, config):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        self.x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(INPUT_SIZE), name='x')
        self.keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float", name='keep_prob')

        self.predict = self.inference(self.x, self.keep_prob)
        self.asking = self.op_ask(self.predict)
```

That works in python:

```
def ask(self, x):
    output = self.s.run(self.asking, feed_dict={
        self.x: x.reshape(64),
        self.keep_prob: 1.0 })
    return output[0] # Expected value
```

Comment: Could you give more context on what you are trying to do, and code snippet that uses Floor?

Comment: @YaoZhang Yes. It was updated. thanks.

Comment: Looks like the library for Floor is not linked. Is this Floor the same as tf.floor (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/math_ops.html)? 

If I were you, I'd consider writing a small/minimum test program that uses floor.